# Cannot figure out why g+ new bigger teaser images wont work

Tags: facebook-opengraph

Hi all I am using Open Graph tags to get g+ (and facebook) to pick up bigger images from my blogs posts.

This link for example: http://www.gamingonlinux.com/articles/update-contagion-zombie-fps-game-still-coming-to-linux-work-in-progress.3734

So for that post in the meta area it has:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.gamingonlinux.com/uploads/articles/tagline_images/1779247106id3734gol.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:title" content="Update: Contagion Zombie FPS Game Still Coming To Linux, Work In Progress" />
<meta property="og:description" content="We let you know recently that the Source engine based zombie survival FPS game Contagion would have news about a Linux version soon. The developers have given a small hint about it now." />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.gamingonlinux.com/articles/update-contagion-zombie-fps-game-still-coming-to-linux-work-in-progress.3734" />
```

It has the correct tags and a big image in the og:image tag, yet g+ still refused to pick it up.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here, but perhaps the tags' order matters. Have you read http://goo.gl/u6oPKe?